# How to resolve non-recursive commit of moved/renamed folders

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

I committed my changes to Branch A (couple file changes + added a new folder and new file in that folder).

Then I merged changes forward to Branch B, however when I am trying to commit I get "Non-recursive commit of moved/renamed folders" warning. In changelist I can see:

New Folder **Added (+)**

New Folder/New File **Normal (+)**

**What I tried?**

1) hit F5 on commit dialog, but that only results into New Folder and New File duplicated entries.

2) perform a full clean-up (including reverting config changes from ignore on commit section)

3) revert and merge again with fully recursive merge depth

TortoiseSVN 1.9.4, Build 27285 - 64 Bit , 2016/04/24 13:59:58

Subversion 1.9.4, -release

Comment: I had the same issue and tbh I just went ahead with the commit. The history is preserved on the committed files. Is there something else you're interested in except the file log?

Comment: @aepure unfortunately, I had to ignore this as well.. I am interested only in the file log, but that's quite important as we are doing group reviews and it's very easy to miss files that were committed in that way. Also I got some response from their forum: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=3222304 however that was useless for me as I did exactly what was suggested..

Comment: did you have problems with ignoring the error message? I did have some problems tbh, eventually I had to do 3 separate commits. So my log is a little dirty.

Comment: @aepure no problems apart from fact that new file is missing from merged revision's change log (but file is there). Probably this isn't a big issue, however it is very annoying that this is happening from time to time and I have no idea why..

Comment: Did the below answer worked @Vladimirs ?

Comment: Even it shows warning, it committed folder with its files in it. Seems a false warning Tortoise version:  1.14

Answer (score 0):

I received this error as well and resolved it by performing this from the command line:

```
svn commit . -m "Fixing build"
```